# How to fix Could not find 'activesupport' (= 6.0.0.rc1) - did find: [activesupport-5.2.3] (Gem::MissingSpecVersionError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I tried installing Rails 6 rc1 on my machine. I then remove each Active* or Action* gems. And I'm encountering this error.

I have tried to do a `bundle update` but to no avail. I am using rbenv.

Can anyone give me a pointer? Thank you!

```
➜  Desktop git:(master) ✗ rails 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    8: from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    7: from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
    6: from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `synchronize'
    5: from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    4: from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
    3: from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
    2: from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
    1: from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1449:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:313:in `to_specs': Could not find 'activesupport' (= 6.0.0.rc1) - did find: [activesupport-5.2.3] (Gem::MissingSpecVersionError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/xxxx/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing it out, I realise that `railties` is the main culprit.

I also made a mistake of uninstall rails the wrong way. Please refer below to find the correct way to uninstall `rails rc`.

So i simply reinstall rails to fix the error above. Then I uninstall it again. Then I uninstall `railties`

```
gem install rails --pre
gem uninstall rails -v 6.0.0.rc1
gem uninstall railsties -v 6.0.0.rc1
```